# Can't find an element using name or text shown on website - python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, element

I have a sample code here which keeps saying that it cant find the element im looking for. Please help me, I want to find the element by the name and not the absolute Xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com')

sleep(5)

x = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Sign Up']").click()
```

Comment: What page are you parsing?Could you give a link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the instagram page you need to induce waits for the page to load and then click the parent a tag of that span.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign up']/parent::a"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however i still had one small issue. Whenever i login to the instagram page, it shows a popup regarding whether i want to show notifications or not and i cant seem to click on the 'Not Now' button even with this method

Comment: //button[text()='Not Now'] would be something like the xpath

Comment: That helped with the notification issue but i still cant seem to click on the user's name with any of the above methods

Comment: Should include the html element you want to click.

Comment: Yes, I tried the same method as the 'not now' but i changed the text. Shouldn't that help?